# Como hago para hacer calculo de cuyos metodos extraigan los datos de la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

mi problema es el siguiente tengo dos metodos que extraen dos datos en String de la base de datos , les hago su parseo con php, pero, dichos datos a la hora de calculo me dan 0 aqui el codigo

```
            $qtt =  intval($d->readQTT($id));
            echo( '<h3 class="display-3">*</h3>');
            $price = doubleval($p->viewPrice($name));

            var_dump($qtt);
            echo '</br>';
            var_dump($price);
```

[image: esto es lo que me muestra]

> esto es lo que me sale cuando hago var_dump

Comment: ¿Imprimiste las variables del cálculo para verificar qué valores tienen? **`echo "Valor de qtt: $qtt y valor de price: $price";`** ¿Qué salida tienes si pones eso?

Comment: si de hecho el me imprime los valores, pero al hacer el calculo total, me imprime 0

Comment: Por favor indica la situación del código en la pregunta. Prueba cada valor por separado copia y pega aquí lo que muestra esto: `var_dump($qtt);` y también `var_dump($price);` No digas, se muestra, no se muestra, no funciona... pon aquí lo que sale.

Comment: listo edite la publicacion y puse una imagen de lo que muestra

Comment: No sé de dónde salen el `8` y el `2.5` que se ven en la imagen, lo que sí es seguro es que tus dos variables equivalen a `0`. El `var_dump` sirve para probar lo que tiene una variable y de qué tipo es. Si observas bien, el primero arroja `int (0)`, indicando que `$qtt` es un dato del tipo `int` y que vale `0`; el segundo arroja `float (0)`, indicando que `$price` es una variable del tipo `float` y que vale `0`. Tienes que revisar los métodos con los que manejas esos datos, porque te están devolviendo `0` en ambos casos. Siempre que algo no te funcione, prueba las variables con `var_dump`

Comment: el 8 y 2.5 son variables que tiene la base de datos como varchar , entonces , en el metodo los selecciono y le hago un parseo, pero como dices tu , puede ver algo en la funcion que no funcione, a lo mejor tengo que cambiar de la bases de datos alguna caractericticas de los datos

Comment: Correcto, tienes que ver: 1º. ¿qué está llegando en `$id` y en `$name`; Si llegan los datos que deben llegar en esas dos variables, entonces debes verificar lo que hacen con ellas los métodos  `readQTT` y `viewPrice`. Todo eso lo puedes verificar con `var_dump`, hacer como un seguimiento de los datos a ver si están llegando bien o si es que se pierden en alguno de esos métodos. Son técnicas de depuración que es preciso aprender y te vas a ahorrar horas tratando de ver dónde está el problema.